# CoreAudio error and crash on AVAudioEngine.connect

Tags: ios, swift, audiounit, avaudioengine

I'm attempting to connect an `AVAudioUnitEffect` to an instance of `AVAudioEngine` like so:

```
required init(inputFormat: AVAudioFormat, outputFormat: AVAudioFormat, andAVAudioEngine avAudioEngine:AVAudioEngine) {
    self.inputFormat = inputFormat
    self.outputFormat = outputFormat

    self.avAudioEngine = avAudioEngine
    self.myAudioUnit = MyAVAudioUnit()

    super.init()

    avAudioEngine.attach(myAudioUnit)
    avAudioEngine.connect(myAudioUnit, to: avAudioEngine.outputNode, format: self.inputFormat)
}
```

The overarching class is simply a subclass of `NSObject` and `MyAudioUnit` is a subclass of `AVAudioUnitEffect`.

At seemingly random times, the last line of this initializer (the call to `connect`) will throw a SIGABRT with the following error: `com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio: error -10875`

Which amounts to `kAudioUnitErr_FailedInitialization`.

Can anyone shed some light on this error and what might be going on here? I thought that maybe the initializer for `MyAVAudioUnit` was failing, but its internal initializer (`init(audioComponentDescription: AudioComponentDescription)`) does not throw any errors and has a non-optional return type. Has anyone else had any experience with this particular error?

**UPDATE**

Here is the initialization of `inputFormat`:

```
guard let stereoFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32,
                                        sampleRate: 44100,
                                        channels: 2,
                                        interleaved: false) else {
                                            return                                             
}

let numChannels = UInt32(10)
guard let multiChannelLayout = AVAudioChannelLayout(layoutTag: kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Unknown | numChannels) else {
    return
}

inputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: stereoFormat.commonFormat,
                                   sampleRate: stereoFormat.sampleRate,
                                   interleaved: stereoFormat.isInterleaved,
                                   channelLayout: multiChannelLayout)
```

`MyAVAudioUnit` contains one additional custom parameter (`volumeParameter`) and is initialized as such:

```
required override init() {
    var componentDescription = AudioComponentDescription()
    componentDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect
    componentDescription.componentSubType = xxxxx
    componentDescription.componentManufacturer = xxxxx
    componentDescription.componentFlags = 0
    componentDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0

    AUAudioUnit.registerSubclass(MyAVAudioUnit.self,
                                 as: componentDescription,
                                 name:"MyAVAudioUnit",
                                 version: UInt32.max)

    super.init(audioComponentDescription: componentDescription)

    guard let paramTree = self.auAudioUnit.parameterTree else { return }
    volumeParameter = paramTree.value(forKey: "volumeParameter") as? AUParameter
}
```

Comment: What kind of `inputFormat`s are you passing in?

Comment: Can you show the `MyAVAudioUnit` or reproduce directly with an unsubclassed  `AVAudioUnitEffect`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman updated original question. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: No problem - nice work getting the 10 channel `AVAudioFormat` working. Can you simplify the repro further? Does the problem reproduce without the parameter? With stereo instead of 10 channel? With a built-in audio unit instead of custom? A runnable snippet would be great.

Comment: Was the audio engine recently stopped?  Did you wait long enough after calling stop? (which is **not** actually synchronous)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what ended up solving this issue. I noticed from crash logs that a print-out of the audio graph just before attempting to connect the audio unit showed this:

`“ ________ GraphDescription ________ AVAudioEngineGraph 0x101538ba0: initialized = 1, running = 0, number of nodes = 23 ”`

The interesting part is that, while `running` is false, `initialized` is *true*. There isn't much documentation on what this `initialized` piece of information means, but I figured out that it shows true when the AVAudioEngine has been started before, but *paused*. Now, I wasn't explicitly calling `avAudioEngine.pause()` from anywhere, but I supposed the system might be initiating the pause as part of `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` (which is what I'm responding to in this whole series of events).

A lot of that is speculation, but it's clear that calling `avAudioEngine.connect()` while a print-out of the engine shows `initialized = 1` (or by inference, the engine is paused) will cause this crash.

The audio engine must be FULLY stopped before attempting to connect audio units. My problem was that my attempt to call `avAudioEngine.stop()` was wrapped in an `if` statement like so:

```
if avAudioEngine.isRunning {
    avAudioEngine.stop()
}
```

Of course, this `if` statement was skipped over because the audio engine was, in fact, not running. So `stop()` was never called. Removing the `if` statement and calling `stop()` unquestionably sets `initialized = 0` on the engine and allows connection without this crash.

Hope this helps someone else. Took me ages to unravel.

Answer (score 1):

You say this happens at “random times” plural.  That might mean you are doing this often, and possibly soon after releasing or de-initing the unit.  Note that the audio unit subsystem runs in different completely asynchronous threads, and so the unit may still be in use by the OS (for a short period of time) after your app stops and releases the unit.  If you put a long enough delay between any stop/release calls and any (re)inits, say perhaps one or two seconds, it may prevent this issue.

Comment: Really great insight. Will definitely give this a try. Thanks!